# Finding The last Date of a Month and return Value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-apps

Help Guys!

I'm looking to find the **last date (col 1)** for a **specific month (col 2 - "december")** and return **value located in Column 3 (col 3 - "Successful Deliveries")**.

I've tried numerous combinations of Filter and Max(). But keep receving #N/A.

The image will make it obvious.

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTKng.png)

**Why:**
I'm trying to create a sheet to calculate the "increase/decrease" month over month on my email subscriber list. Thus need to grab each end of month subscriber number and compare it with other end of months number.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please paste your sample data as "text" in your question, better with expected output. Moreover, you also can paste your formula here, maybe we can tell you what it return `N/A`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (in a google spreadsheet)

```
=vlookup("December", sort({B2:B,A2:C}, 2, 0), 4, 0)
```

Note: depending on your locale, you may have to change the above formula to

```
=vlookup("December"; sort({B2:B\A2:C}; 2; 0); 4; 0)
```

Comment: @Tony Rositano: 
Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation). In other words, if you accept the answer, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job. You will need to specify the year that the month in B2 is referring to.

```
=VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(B2&" 16"),0),A:C,3,FALSE)
```

**Breakdown**

`DATEVALUE(B2&" 16")` Get Excel date with month from `B2` and year 16 (2016)

`EOMONTH(x,0)`        Get the end of month `x` (last day)

`vlookup(x,a:c,3,FALSE)` Lookup `x` if the first column of my range (`a`). Return the value in the `3`rd column. Use exact match (`FALSE`)